Logic Apps, transcoding in XSLT 3.0, replacing values stored in an Azure Storage Table
I have some values to transform on a logic app running some XSLT 3.0 code from ISO3 to ISO2.
Those data are stored in an Azure Table.
I know how to run the transformation within logic app, and I know how to get the data from the table in another step.
I can only imagine the way it's done with Devops using tokens {# ... #}
What would be the correct mechanism to change those values?

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You're doing some XSLT transformation, then in the next step for some reason you're getting some data from Azure table, and then you're asking about DevOps - why? How is it all tied together?


Logic Apps, transcoding in XSLT 3.0, replacing values stored in an Azure Storage Table

As you said that you have transformed and now wanting to  replace then for that use below design:

In json used, the key is column name and value is the value that you wanted to replace and other column values.
Here used:

Values before replacing:

If you give full json in entity section of action , then it will replace like this:
{
"Name":"Bojja",
"Place":"Lingam"
}



If you do not give full json then it will replace like this:
{
"Place":"Jangam"
}



So, even when you use other action (replace entity v2) then also you need to give all entities to replace not just the column and row you want to replace , you need to give all row values as json to get replaced.
